# Pattern for dealing with different File Types

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, file-handling

In my application I fetch files from the user and process it.

Im to limit to a certain scope of file types and each one of these has a different processing approach.

How can I design the application in order that when a new type of file is added, I have to change few to no lines in the controller classes.

Should I be using an Adapter? Wouldn't that be just delegating change responsabilities to another class?

Should I make a representative class for files and deal with them that way?

If possible, provide a (generic) implementation example. It might help to know that Im designing a Spring MVC application and loading files with multipart files. Also, Im checking file type through extension name in the loading file controller [this might have to change].

Comment: What you want is to have a generic interface with a method providing abstraction (could be anything, maybe even `process`) and havr concrete implementations of this interface for each file type. You will then have a factory method returning you a concrete instance of said generic interface based on the type of the file you are trying to open.

Comment: Generic interface is in. On the rest let me see if I understood: I create a factory that takes the input and produce an object of the correct type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorators would fit, one implementation for each of the types, one more as a facade (or dispatcher ? not sure about the term here) routing to the proper implementation.

The facade and the multiple decorator should implements the same interface, here is an example :

```
public interface FileProces{
    public void process(File file);
    public boolean canProcess(File file);
}
```

Each decorator should handle his own type of file :

```
public class JpgFileProces implements FileProces{
    public void process(File file){
        if(!canProcess(file)){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        ...
    }

    public boolean canProcess(File f){
        return f.getContentType.equals("image/jpeg");
    }
}
```

Then the Facade :

```
public FacadeFileProces{
    public Set<FileProcess> setProcess;
    public void process(File file){
         for(FileProcess process : setProcess){ 
               if(process.canProcess(file)){
                     process.process(file);
                     break;// you can either do that of for more security, either ensure that you have only one processor and not multiple that are registered.
               }
         }
    }

    public boolean canProcess(File file){
       for(FileProcess process : setProcess){
           if(process.canProcess(file)){
               return true;
           }
       }
       return false;
    }
}
```

Note : DavidPacker in his comment talked about factory : his solution is more usefull is your `FileProcessor` are not stateless. If they're not, using a factory returning only singletons is the same that I did, I'm just masking the fact that I have sublayers.

Comment: But then I'll still have to "swich/else if" somewhere to get the correct classes... No? That's where I'm finding trouble, for it will demand some length of maintenance.

Comment: @TiagoSirious the "if" is in the for loop in the sample i gave. There is only one if in the for loop. The only thing i didn't show you here is how to register you JpgFileProcess in the FacadeFileProcess because i don't know if you use tools like dependency injection (which help a lot), otherwise you can just make JpgFileProcess's constructor take the FacaceFileProcess as a parameter and let him self registering in).

Comment: So I made a FIle factory that does this: String type = file.getContentType().toString().toLowerCase();
  IProcessableFile processableFile;
  switch (type) {
  case "text/plain":
   processableFile = new FileTxt(file.getName());
  default:
   processableFile = null;
  }

Comment: @TiagoSirious you can do it like this, I just did it differently, mine is a bit more flexible, but that flexibility may not be necessary to you. I edited it a bit so you can see the whole picture.

Comment: Ok, now I see it! I was missing the canProcess part!

Comment: Another thing that is not clear yet. So I add to the set of FileProcess all the File classes that I create, and then it will try to find a match, rigth?

Comment: yes you have to fill the field `setProcess`. You have multiple way of doing this : using DI, set the field as static and use static initializer in FileProcess, ...